# Laplace-Beltrami operator self-adjoint in context of Markov processes and their infinitesimal generators

Tags: riemannian-geometry, markov-process, stochastic-differential-equations, laplacian, self-adjoint-operators

Let $d\vec{X} = \vec{\mu}(\vec{X})dt +\sigma(\vec{X})d\vec{B}_t$ be a multidimensional SDE. It has infinitesimal generator
$$\mathscr{L}f = \vec{\mu}^T \nabla f + \frac12 \operatorname{Tr}(\Sigma \nabla^2 f),$$
where $\Sigma = \sigma \sigma^T$ for smooth functions $f\in C^2$. The adjoint operator $\mathscr{L}^*$ is found by differentiating with respect to $t$ the integral
$$\int f(y) p(t,x,y)dy$$
and using Ito's lemma, integration by parts and some regularity to get
$$\int f(y) p_t(t,x,y)dy = \int \mathscr{L}f(y) p(t,x,y)dy=\int f(y) \mathscr{L}^* p(t,x,y)dy,$$
obtaining the Fokker-Planck equation
$$p_t = \mathscr{L}^* p.$$
Explicitly,
$$\mathscr{L}^* p = -\partial_i [p \mu^i]+\frac12 \partial_{ij}^2 [p\Sigma_{ij}],$$
where we have omitted the summation signs over $i$ and $j$ to de-clutter the notation.

Let $\tilde{p}(t,x,y) =p(t,x,y) \sqrt{\det g(y)}$ for a PD matrix field $g(y)$. Further let
$$\tilde{\mathscr{L}} p := \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det g}} \mathscr{L}^* \tilde{p} =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det g}}\mathscr{L}^* (p \sqrt{\det g}).$$

The above work shows that, with $\nu(dy) = \sqrt{\det g(y)} dy$,
$$\int f(y) \tilde{\mathscr{L}} p(t,x,y) \nu(dy)=\int \mathscr{L}[f(y)] p(t,x,y) \nu(dy),$$
in other words the adjoint of $\mathscr{L}$ *with respect to the volume measure* is $\tilde{\mathscr{L}}$. Therefore, when $\mathscr{L} = \frac12 \Delta_g$, i.e. is one half the Laplace-Beltrami operator, we **should** get $\mathscr{L} = \tilde{\mathscr{L}}$, since it is well known that the [Laplace-Beltrami operator is self-adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator#Formal_self-adjointness) with reference to the volume measure. In this case $\mu =\frac12 \nabla_g \cdot g^{-1}$, the manifold divergence of the rows of $g^{-1}$, and $\Sigma = g^{-1}$, the inverse-metric tensor. Precisely,
$$\nabla_g \cdot \vec{f} = \frac{1}{\sqrt \det g} \nabla \cdot (\sqrt{\det g}\vec{f})$$
for vector fields $\vec{f}$.

**Questions**:

1. Is this all correct?
2. How can I actually show the Laplace-Beltrami operator is self-adjoint in this context/language $\tilde{\mathscr{L}} = \mathscr{L}$? i.e.

$$\tilde{\mathscr{L}} f = -\frac{1}{\sqrt \det g} \partial_i \left[0.5 \nabla_g \cdot g^{i} \sqrt{\det g} f\right]+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\det g}} \partial_{ij}^2 [g^{ij} \sqrt{\det g} f]$$
$$ = (0.5 \nabla_g \cdot g^{-1})^T \nabla f +\frac12 \operatorname{Tr}(g^{-1} \nabla^2 f)?$$
I am familiar with Christofell symbols $\Gamma_{ik}^r$, their relation to manifold divergence etc. My guess is to use Jacobi's formula for derivatives of determinants and some properties of $\Gamma_{ik}^r$, $g$, and $\nabla_g \cdot g^{-1}$ and simplify, simplify, simplify. I will try to write this out tonight.

**Update:**
I think using the form
$$\Delta_g f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det g}} \partial_i (\sqrt{\det g} g^{ij} \partial_j f)$$
makes it easy to directly show, integrating by parts twice,
$$\int \Delta_g [f(y)] p(t,x,y) \nu(dy) = \int f(y) \Delta_g[p(t,x,y)] \nu(dy),$$
hence it follows that $\Delta_g$ is self-adjoint (w.r.t. to $\nu$) and thus we must also have $\Delta_g = 2\tilde{\mathscr{L}}$.

But, I would still like to see direct computations that show $\tilde{\mathscr{L}}=\frac12 \Delta_g$ (which I am trying to work out the idea I mentioned above).